# What's the differences between "The Improper Princess" and "Dealing with Dragons"?

Tags: enchanted-forest-chronicles

Patricia C. Wrede's *Enchanted Forest Chronicles* started as "The Improper Princess" from [*Spaceships and Spells*](https://archive.org/details/spaceshipsspells00yole/page/n11/mode/2up) of 1987, before it was expanded into *Dealing with Dragons* three years later.

What changed between those versions, beyond just getting longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, "The Improper Princess" ends at what's basically mid-way into Chapter 2:

> Still smiling, she started forward to begin her new duties.

Starting from the beginning, and comparing it to the Kindle Sample and Archive.org otherwise:

There's been parentheses removed from around:

> mainly for show - it had been centuries since a dragon had come east

Punctuation change: The apostrophe was removed here:

> pinned like her sisters'

King and Queen are now capitalized titles.

"them then" is now "them, then

"A few weeks later" is visually sectioned off from the parts before it.

"done about Cimorene" becomes "done about her"

"destination. For" becomes "destination, for"

"sighed Cimorene's lady-in-waiting" becomes "Cimorene's lady-in-waiting sighed"

"yesterday," she" becomes "yesterday." She"

"such" is italically emphasized.

kingdom was > kingdom is

"end of the conversation" ends a section.

---

Now we're getting into some big changes after "coaxingly", where almost two whole lines have been changed:

> "Well, no," Thernadil replied, looking sheepish.
> "Oh, good. Then you'll [...]"

To:

> "Well, not exactly [...]
> "Oh, good," Cimorene said, correctly [...] *at all*. "Then you'll [...]

---

"I'd rather be [...]" starts a new paragraph

small, green > small green

pardon; > pardon.

want to marry him? > want to?

Just turn all ; into .

said about > *said* about

personages > people

difficulties, if > difficulties if

Cimorene spent > She spent [also section start]

They door > The door [first typo fix]

went inside > went in

The inside of the > Inside, the

---

Another big change:

> feel frightened. She felt behind her

To adding a sentence in-between:

> feel frightened. She wondered [...]. She felt behind her

---

fencing lessons, and > fencing lessons and

the Latin, > the Latin

The voices belonged to dragons. [Becomes an isolated paragraph]

---

> Each of the males [...] horns at all.

Is new.

So's

> They were much scarier [...] books.

---

X, Y, Noun phrasing seems to all be X Y Noun:

> shining, green scales

etc

---

really would > really *would*

all of its teeth > all her teeth

who really had > who had

Its scales > His scales

"Kazul!" starts a new line now.

had to eat him; [No ; change]

princess volunteering > princess, volunteering

suggested the yellowish-green > suggested the yellowish green

---

Reordered lines:

Originally:

> "Give her a trial run first,"
> "You can't be serious, Kazul,"
> "I like cherries jubilee,"

---

"And for that you'd take on a [...]" has stuff added before it.

yellowish-green > yellowish green

She was relieved to find that > To her relief,

: > .

dark she > dark, she

its tail > her tail

chamber > cave x2

; > .

meantime > meantime,

start > begin

; > .

"Draco [starts new section]

---

And that seems to be all the changes.

Seems like minor punctuation, phrasing, and formatting changes, with a few changed and added lines. Biggest change would probably be the existence of the sexing of dragons other than Roxim.